# What supply voltage for the Abracon crystal oscillators?

Tags: voltage, crystal

I'm considering the Abracon [ABM8W-13.5600MHZ-4-B1U-T3](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/abracon-llc/ABM8W-13.5600MHZ-4-B1U-T3/535-14013-1-ND/7173198) Crystal but I'm having difficulty finding the maximum and minimum supply voltages. Does anybody know how to obtain this information (I've tried emailing the manufacturer)?

Voltage in my project will range from 4.2v to 3.2v.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a crystal. Crystals don't have a supply. They are passive elements.

You might be confusing this with an integrated oscillator, maybe, which contains a crystal, an inverting amplifier and an output buffer in one package. Those need a supply voltage and are useful as standalone oscillation generators. The crystal you link to needs to be driven from something that has clock pins, e.g. a microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Marcus Müller. What I don't understand now, is why does this crystal (https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/crystal-oscillators/1712679/), for example, have a specified maximum voltage then?

Comment: That is because it is not a passive quartz crystal, it is a integrated crystal oscillator.

Comment: @GlynDavidson that's why I wrote the second paragraph. Just as justme says, that's not just a crystal, but a crystal oscillator.

Comment: Ahhh, much appreciated, I thought that crystal was just an abbreviation of crystal oscillator. More research required on my part then. Many thanks.